# Sails.JS and Hypermedia HATEOAS Examples?

Tags: html, api, hateoas, sails.js, hypermedia

Does anyone have any good examples implementing an HTML5 Hypermedia (HATEOAS) API using SailsJS, or if that would even be a good idea?  And if not, why not?